# React Redux parent and child component sharing state URL keeps reloading old ID

Tags: reactjs, redux

so I have a redux store with has this basic structure:

```
{
    user: {
        id: 1,
        currentCompanyId: 2,
    }
    companyDetails: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Joes Company'
    },
    otherCompanies: [2,3,4],
}
```

I have a parent page which in the header has a dropdown that allows the user to link / switch to another company.

The parent component needs to know which company is selected so it can show the name in the heading.

The child component displays the details of the current company.

There will be various types of companies and the url's / sections will be different for each type.  So in the child component I was trying to set the user's company and then load the details of that company.

The child component doesn't need to directly reference the user or current company.

So what I was doing was in the child component I would listen in `willmount` and `willreceiveprops` for a change to the url, then fire an action to update the user company.  This will then cause the parent to re render as the user object has changed.  Which in turn will create a new / remount the child component.  So far this seemed logical.

The issue is that when I have selected company 2 and try to switch to company 3, it will set the company to 3, but then reset it back to 2 again.

I am not sure if this is to do with the URL having not updated or something.  I have gone around in circles so much now that I am not sure what the workflow should be anymore.

**edit**

if I comment out `this.loadContractorInfo(contractorId);` from `ContractorHome.js` in `componentWillMount()` it will work correctly (i.e. the URL stays with the number in the link, vs reverting to the old one.  I assume this is to do with redux actions are async, and although I am not doing any network calls it is some race condition between getting data for the contractor page and the `contextheader` wanting to display / update the current company

**edit 2**

so to confirm.  I have loaded the page at the root of the site, all fine.  I select a company / contractor from the dropdown.  this loads fine.  I go to change that selection to a different contractor from the dropdown.  The first component to be hit will be the parent (contextheader), the `location` prop in nextprops will have updated to have the correct ID in the URL.  the method execution at this point will NOT update any thing, no actions are fired.  It then hits the child (contractorhome) willreceiveprops method, again the URL in location is good as is the match params.  I have commented out all code in willrecieveprops so it does not do anything here either.  It will then go back to the parent willreceive props and the location will have gone back to the previous ID in the URL.

`app.js` snippet:

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="app">
    <Router>
      <div>
        <div className="bodyContent">
          <ContextHeader />
          <Switch>
            {/* Public Routes */}
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/contractor" component={ContractorRoute} />
            <Route path="/building" component={BuildingRoute} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
}
```

`contextheader`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const { setCompany } = this.props;

const currentInfo = this.props.sharedInfo && this.props.sharedInfo.currentCompany;
const newInfo = nextProps.sharedInfo && nextProps.sharedInfo.currentCompany;

if (newInfo && newInfo.id && (!currentInfo || currentInfo.id !== newInfo.id)) {
  setCompany(newInfo.id, newInfo.type);
 }
}

render() {
  const { user, companies, notifications } = this.props;
  /* render things here */
  }
  );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
user: state.user,
sharedInfo: state.sharedInfo,
companies: state.companies,
notifications: state.notifications,
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
setCompany: (companyId, type) => dispatch(setCurrentCompany(companyId,   type)),
});

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContextHeader));
```

`contractorRoute`:

```
const ContractorRoute = ({ match }) => (
  <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.path}/:contractorId`} component={ContractorHome} />
    </Switch>
  );
```

`contractorHome`

```
  componentWillMount() {    
const contractorId = parseInt(this.props.match.params.contractorId, 10);
this.setSharedCompany(contractorId);
this.loadContractorInfo(contractorId);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
const newContractorId = parseInt(nextProps.match.params.contractorId, 10);        

if (this.props.match.params.contractorId !== nextProps.match.params.contractorId) {
  this.setSharedCompany(newContractorId);
}
  }

  setSharedCompany(contractorId) {
const { sharedInfo, setCompany } = this.props;

if (typeof contractorId === 'number') {
  if (!sharedInfo || !sharedInfo.currentCompany || !sharedInfo.currentCompany.id || sharedInfo.currentCompany.id !== contractorId) {
    setCompany(contractorId);
  }
}
  }

loadContractorInfo(contractorId) {
const { sharedInfo, getContractorInfo, busy } = this.props;

if (!busy && sharedInfo && sharedInfo.currentCompany && sharedInfo.currentCompany.id === contractorId) {
  getContractorInfo(contractorId);
}
}

  render() { /*render lots of things here*/};


 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selector = state.contractor.details;

  return {    
    sharedInfo: state.sharedInfo,
    details: selector.info,
    error: selector.request != null ? selector.request.error : null,

    busy: selector.request && selector.request.busy,
  };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getContractorInfo: contractorId => dispatch(getContractor(contractorId)),
  setCompany: contractorId => dispatch(setSharedinfoCurrentCompany(contractorId, 'contractor')), 
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContractorHome);
```

Comment: Post your component's code

Comment: Is data flow one directional and route is the source of truth?

Comment: @MikhailZhuravlev yes the route should be the source of truth.  the parent component doesn't know anything about the "type" of truth, or its params from the URL, which is why I tried to get it to find the values from the store and use the child component to update them

Comment: found the problem... user / coder error.  in the render there was a redirect in a route that used a parameter that was sometimes the old ID not the new one